# Git untrack a file in one remote but keep it in a different remote

Tags: git

I have a repository called `xyz` and it has two remotes `A` and `B`. `A` is owned by me but I have no push access to `B` (so I can't change anything in remote `B`). `B` has a bunch of files I don't want, so I untracked them on my remote `A`. Now when I pull from `B`, git gives me this warning:

```
The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge
```

I know I can just delete them locally, but I want to keep some of those files locally.

Is there any command/method that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, but in fact, the question itself does not make sense as phrased:

> `B` has a bunch of files I don't want, so I untracked them on my remote `A` ...

A *remote* is a short name, like `origin`, that exists in some Git repository, that serves to hold a URL for some *other* Git repository.  Being just a name, a remote doesn't actually hold any files at all.  Presumably you mean to use the word "remote" here to stand in for particular Git repositories.

Unfortunately, even if we make these adjustments, we're still left with something that doesn't quite match up with how Git works.  We get a statement of the form *I have repositories R1 and R2.  In R1, there are some tracked files, and in R2, I made them untracked.*  This can be used to mean something, but it's not what I think you mean.<sup>1</sup>  The problem here is the very definition of the phrase *untracked file*, which is not a property of a *repository*, really.  To see what I mean we have to dive into what a repository is and does, and how commits work, and are constructed and deconstructed, in Git.

---

<sup>1</sup>[Obligatory reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dTRKCXC0JFg)

---

#### A Git repository is a collection of commits, plus some side items

Those new to Git, and casual users of Git, tend to think that Git is all about files, but it's not.  It's really all about *commits*.  To a first approximation, a Git repository is just a big database of internal Git objects, where the objects that we use and care about are commits.

- Each commit in the database is numbered.  These numbers are not simple counting numbers—they aren't commit #1, followed by #2, then #3, and so on—but instead are big, ugly, and random-looking *hash IDs*.  Each commit gets its own unique hash ID, and every Git in the universe agrees that *that* commit gets *that* hash ID.  (This is the truly magic part, and is how Git functions as a *distributed* version control system—a DVCS—and not just a plain VCS.)
- Commits are 100% read-only. For that matter, all internal Git objects share this feature, because their hash IDs are cryptographic checksums of their contents.  The database is a simple [key-value store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key%E2%80%93value_database) where the values must hash back to their keys; this is how Git provides data integrity, by checking that the checksum it used to *find* the data matches the checksum *of* the data.
- A commit stores two things:

  - The main data in a commit is a complete snapshot of every file that Git knew about when you, or whoever, made that commit.  (Technically this is a *tree* object in the commit's metadata.)
  - Besides the main data, each commit stores some *metadata*, including the name and email address of the person who made the commit, some date-and-time-stamps, and so on.  Crucially for Git (but unexplored in this answer), each commit stores the hash ID of some *previous* commit or commits, which means Git can use any commit to find an earlier commit.

Because everything in a commit is read-only, the *files* in the commit are read-only too.  And, because every commit stores every file, Git keeps the files in a de-duplicated format (which also involves compressing and hashing the file's content, using more Git internal objects).  That way, no matter how many commits you make, if they keep re-using the same files over and over, the repository hardly grows any bigger: the only space needed is for the commit itself, not its files, which are all duplicates.

But because the files inside a commit are stored in this read-only, Git-only internal format, they're actually quite useless for getting any *work* done.  This is where we get into the difference between what Git calls a *bare* repository, and the kind of repository where we do work.  (There's no special term for this, it's just a non-bare repository.)

#### Your work-tree, or how Git makes a commit useful

In order to make a commit useful—so that we can *see* the files and work on and with them—Git must *extract* some commit.  The commit contains a bunch of files, in some Git-only form; we need them in ordinary everyday form.  So Git copies them *out* of the commit, into a work area.  Git calls this work area your *working tree* or *work-tree*.

Your work-tree is, in a very important sense, not actually *in* the repository.  It's more like it's just *next to* the repository: adjacent, right along side the repository.  If you look at all files in your work-tree, including the hidden ones, you'll find a `.git` directory<sup>2</sup>.  The repository proper is here.  This is where Git stores the files, in their compressed internal format, as *blob objects* in the `.git/objects` directory.  They do not have normal file names here.

The point here is that the `.git` directory is a sub-directory of your work-tree, not the other way around.  So your files are *yours*, to do with as you will, in *your* work-tree.  You must be careful not to damage the *repository* files in the `.git` sub-directory: those are Git's, to do with as Git will.  Git just sometimes copies files *out* of the repository, to your work-tree, when you ask it to do so.  In the process, it expands out the compressed and Git-ified internal objects, turning them back into ordinary files.

---

<sup>2</sup>If you prefer the term *folder*, that's fine, and note that some work-trees—particularly those added through `git worktree add`—have a `.git` *file* instead of a `.git` directory / folder.  Git makes relatively few promises about what goes on inside the `.git` directory, including whether it's even a directory.  This is a change from very early versions of Git, which were quite cavalier about letting you reach into the `.git` directory and change stuff.

---

#### Git's index, or making new commits

Given that we now realize that Git—like most VCSes—has *committed* files and *useful* files that are kept separate, and that you work on the *useful* ones—you might expect the `git commit` command to scan through your work-tree files and use those to make the new commit.  That's not how Git works, though.  (Other VCSes *do* do that, which makes them a lot easier to use.)

Instead, Git keeps, at all times, a *third* "copy" of each file, in what Git calls the *index*, or the *staging area*, or—rarely these days—the *cache*.  The word "copy" is in quotes here because the "copy" of that file is in Git's internal frozen *format*.  It is already de-duplicated and is ready to go into a new commit.  It's not actually *in* a commit, though, so it can be *replaced*.

When you edit a file in your work-tree, you need to tell Git to copy the updated file back into Git's ready-to-commit area: the index / staging-area.  The `git add` command does that.  More precisely, `git add file` tells Git that it should make the *index* copy of *`file`* match the *work-tree* copy of *`file`*.  That includes going so far as to *remove* the index copy of the file, if you've already removed the work-tree copy yourself.

Note that `git rm` will remove a file from two places: Git's index *and* your work-tree.  This is usually more convenient than having to first remove the file from your work-tree, then using `git add` to (weirdly) remove the copy from Git's index.  But that's what this is all about.  The `git add` command copies the work-tree file to the index, and if the file wasn't in the index before, well, now it is.  Or, if the file is gone, it removes the file from Git's index.  No matter what, the index copy now matches the work-tree copy, and `git add` has finished its job.

What this means is that, to a first approximation again anyway,<sup>3</sup> the index represents the *next commit you plan to make*.  Before you actually *do* make the next commit, it's your job to update Git's index.  To do that, you will usually update some files in *your* work-tree, then use `git add` to copy the updated files back into Git's index.  Now you're ready to run `git commit`.

When you do run `git commit`, Git gathers any metadata it needs to *make* the new commit.  Then it turns the index's contents into a frozen snapshot, to store as the new commit's data; it adds the rest of the metadata, including the time right now (to the second) as the date-and-time-stamps; and it writes out the commit.  This produces the cryptographic hash ID for the new commit, which is guaranteed to be unique.<sup>4</sup>

The new commit now contains all the files that Git knew about.  Those were the files that were in Git's index, when you ran `git commit`.  That's where the files come from.

---

<sup>3</sup>The index takes on an expanded role during a conflicted merge, and has a bunch of smaller roles, one of which we'll see in a moment.

<sup>4</sup>*Cough* Pigeonhole principle?  What [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)?

---

#### Untracked files

Note that, in all of this fussing-about with work-tree (yours to do with as you will) and index (Git's), there is *nothing that says the files in these two have to match up*.  The files that *are* in the index *will be* in the next commit, in whatever form they have in the index at the time you run `git commit`.  But some files can be in your work-tree, and yet not in Git's index.

**This is what an untracked file is.**  It is simply a file that is in your work-tree *right now*, but that is not in Git's index *right now*.

You can change which files are in your work-tree.  Any ordinary computer command can do this!  But you can also change which files are in Git's index: `git rm --cached` can take one or more out, and `git add` can put one or more in *or* take one or more out (or even do both at the same time), by making the index copy or copies match the work-tree ones.

#### `git checkout` fills Git's index and writes to your work-tree

When you use `git checkout` to select some particular *commit*, you're telling Git that it should:

- fill its index *from* that commit (so that you'll be ready to make new commits), and
- change the files in your work-tree to match those in that commit.

When there's some untracked file in your work-tree, that file isn't in Git's index, so Git *might* not have to do anything with it.  But what if that file *is* in the *commit* you want to switch to?  Now Git has to *put that file into its index*, by the rules of `git checkout`.  Then it will have to *clobber* the (currently untracked) file in your work-tree, to make it match the index copy that it gets from the commit.

#### This is why the short answer is "no"

The tracked-ness, or un-tracked-ness, of each file is something that you can control, but it's also *dynamic*.  It is not a property of a *repository*.  It is a property of Git's index, which Git will *fill from a commit*.  The files that are in some commit are in that commit forever, because no part of any commit can ever be changed.

If you take a file out of Git's index and make new commits, the new commits will lack the file.  That's all there is to that.  If you put the file into Git's index and make new commits, the new commits will have the file, and that's all there is to that, too.  When you use an *existing* commit that *has* the file, Git will want to fill in its index.

#### Sparse checkout provides a sort of workaround, but it is not easy to use

Git has a feature called *sparse checkout*.  This works by making use of the fact that Git's index really is separate from your work-tree.  When Git is checking out some commit—whether by a branch name that finds a hash ID, or by a raw hash ID directly, for instance—Git *is* going to fill in its index.  But what if we didn't have Git copy *all* the files from its index to our own work-trees?  That's what sparse checkout can do.

I have not investigated to see whether sparse checkout "plays well" with untracked files that will have the same name as the index copy, but because Git uses the "skip worktree" bit in the index's cache entry, this *should* work.  That's all just theory, but depending on your situation, you might be able to use this mode of working.  It's worth noting that if and when you do this, new commits you make will have the file in them (because it will be in Git's index when you make those new commits) even though the file either is not in your work-tree at all, or has totally different content in your work-tree.

(Unfortunately, sparse checkout is not easy to set up, and may have rough edges.  There's ongoing work in Git now to make it better, though this is not the intended use case.)